# setting the exact x,y positions of buttons in a relative layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was wondering how i could set the exact x,y positions of a button in a relative layout. I want to try and not use an absolute layout. When i looked at similar posts most of them only showed how to align things exactly in the center or to the left of the screen, is there a way to align things at an exact position maybe by subtracting the distance from a margin by w/e dpi

Comment: well i wanna make a game where the users can drag and drop objects if i make it so that all images are based on dpi and only positions are based on pixels with the absouloute layout do u think it could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RelativeLayout imply the concept of relative position. You can only set a position of a widget in Relation with other widgets positions (aligned to the left, under...) or the container (bottom, top etc etc).

you can position the widget and then try to adjust the distance with the padding attribute (there is a padding for every direction, left,right,bottom,top). With these maybe you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how i could set the exact x,y positions of a button in
>   a relative layout

Those 2 things are diametrically opposed concepts. What is it you're trying to do? Why do you need things to be at exact x,y positions?

Answer (score 0):

There might be but I don't know it. However I would think that simply placing a relative layout inside of an absolute layout but not filling it and placing your buttons on the exposed part of the absolute layout would work. Unless you REALLY don't want to use absolute at all.